# How to create Play 1.x cookie for just the base domain (no sub domains)

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, subdomain

I want to create a cookie that will be shareable across my sub domains. I'm trying to use the setCookie method shown here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/api/play/mvc/Http.Response.html#setCookie-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

If I do the following it creates a cookie, but the domain is "xxxx.mydomain.com"... so the full domain:

```
response.setCookie("loggedIn", "true");
```

If I do the following, the cookie never shows up in my browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
response.setCookie("webLoggedIn", "true", ".mydomain.com", "/", 3600, false);
```

When I try and change the setting application.defaultCookieDomain that seems to break my cookies, but I think its because I'm testing on a different domain than the production domain which is what I set the default too.

Answer (score 1):

On Play Framework 1 the right way is by setting the `application.defaultCookieDomain` [property](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/configuration) to something like `yourdomain.com` (without the prefix dot). This way all cookies will be setted to only the domain itself.

If you use this settings with `.yourdomain.com` then all cookies will be visible to all subdomains, like `www.yourdomain.com` or `another.yourdomain.com`, other than the domain itself.

You mention that you are testing on different domain than the production, then you can use a default domain setting for development environments and the [specific domain for production](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.3.2/ids%20Manage%20application.conf), like:

```
application.defaultCookieDomain=localhost

# Production configuration
%prod.application.defaultCookieDomain=yourdomain.com
```

Alternatively, you can change temporarily your hosts file to resolve the production domain to your localhost ip, (/etc/hosts on Linux and OSX):

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

Note: on Play >= 2.1 the property was changed to `session.domain` and on Play >= 2.4 the property was changed again to `play.http.session.domain`.